# AngularJS: how do i get data into an object and array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, json

i am trying to get data out of a spreadsheet into an array. I have already stored the data in javascript variables. But now i need those varriables to get stored as an obect in my array. here is my code:

```
this.json = function(){
        jQuery.getJSON("http://cors.io/?u=https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/1l4XTKaLZihj5WDRuZJE5Y7RQ7Cr7SD_-tH0ctwhizWc/od6/public/values?alt=json").success(function(data) {
            console.log(data.feed.entry);
            //try
            for (var i = 0; i < data.feed.entry.length; i++) {

                var id = data.feed.entry[i].gsx$id.$t;
                var name = data.feed.entry[i].gsx$name.$t;
                var price = data.feed.entry[i].gsx$price.$t;
                var notcompatiblewith =     data.feed.entry[i].gsx$notcompatiblewith.$t;

                this.parts[i] = {"id": id, "name": name, "price": price, "comp": notcompatiblewith, "canAdd": true, "added": false};    
            };
        });
    };
```

i call the function this.json in my html with ng-init="myctrl.json()" and it calls it perfectly. in my console on inspect element i get the error: 'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property '0' of undefined'

my array should look like this if it is initialised well:

```
{
id: 1,
name: 'vitamine A',
price: 3,
canAdd: true,
added: false,
comp: [2, 5]
},
{
id: 2,
name: 'vitamine B',
price: 5,
canAdd: true,
added: false,
comp: [1, 3]
},
{
id: 3,
name: 'vitamine C',
price: 2,
canAdd: true,
added: false,
comp: [2]
},
{
id: 4,
name: 'Opium',
price: 20.95,
canAdd: true,
added: false,
comp: []
},
{
id: 5,
name: 'steroids',
price: 12.5,
canAdd: true,
added: false,
comp: [1]
}
```

edit: the array parts in initialised under my controller like this

```
var parts = [];
```

and is declared in my controller as

```
this.parts = parts;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to initialize `this.parts` variable with empty `Array` object:

```
this.json = function(){
    jQuery.getJSON("http://cors.io/?u=https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/1l4XTKaLZihj5WDRuZJE5Y7RQ7Cr7SD_-tH0ctwhizWc/od6/public/values?alt=json").success(function(data) {
        console.log(data.feed.entry);
        this.parts = []; // <-- this line was added
        // skipped
    });
};
```

Also you can use `push` method of Array instead of `this.parts[i] = ...`:

```
this.parts.push({"id": id, ... });
```

Answer (score 1):

When you call `this` it refers to jQuery. Therefor `parts` does not exist.

Also, you're doing it wrong. You should use a service for it, and in the service there's a angular's `$http` for handling ajax requests.

In your way you're not using angular correctly.

Read here: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried :

```
this.parts[i].push({"id": id, "name": name, "price": price, "comp": notcompatiblewith, "canAdd": true, "added": false});
```

Because :

```
this.parts[i] = {"id": id, "name": name, "price": price, "comp": notcompatiblewith, "canAdd": true, "added": false};
```

This will end up assigning only one value to array.Everytime array will get upadated of latest value and deleting previous value.

Comment: yes, the first comment told me to do it that way, but i left out the [i] and it worked just fine